# How to use a separate object for collisions

Tags: constraints

I have an export/import tool for blender and it supports collisions, but not in a Blender-friendly way. I'd like to improve it so that collisions are imported as actual blender collisions that work the way a Blender user would expect.

One issue is that in game files, the collision is provided separately from the visual mesh so that it can be much simpler than the visual mesh. Is there a conventional Blender way of doing this? So instead of putting Rigid Body physics on the object with a "Mesh" collision shape, use a "Rigid Body Constraint" or "Compound Parent" shape?

I could make something up using one or the other of these but if this is a known thing already, I'd rather do what people expect.